# PHP Why foreach loop skip same value from array?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, foreach

I have a two arrays inputs from the users. One is id of the of product and other one is amount of the product. My problem is starting when user input same value of the amount (ex. 5 mallboro, 7 coca cola, 6 fanta, 5 pepsi). The code just show pepsi but not the mallboro. Where is problem? amount is $kolicina variable. Here is my code

```
                $idProizvod = implode(',', array_reverse($_POST['idProizvod']));
                $kolicina = implode(",", $_POST['kolicina']);

                $kolicina = array_reverse($_POST['kolicina']);



                 $sql="SELECT kodProizvoda,imeProizvoda,jedinica,cijena FROM proizvodi WHERE memberID IN ($idProizvod) ORDER BY FIELD(memberID, $idProizvod)";
                 $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);


                    // Fetch all
                    $array= mysqli_fetch_all($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);


                    $brojac = 0;
                    foreach (array_combine($kolicina, $array) as $code => $name) {

                        $name= implode("<td>", $name);
                        echo '<tr>';
                        echo '<td> <input type="number" id="'.$brojac.'" class="kol" name="kolicina[]" value="'.$code.'"></td>';
                        echo '<td> '.$name.'</td>';
                        echo '<td id="iznostbl'.$brojac.'"> </td>';
                        echo '</tr>';
                        $brojac++;

                      }




}
```

Comment: The issue is that you are setting the amount as the key within array_combine. With duplicate keys, later values overwrite previous values as you can't have two keys that are the same. Array_combine will process first and create a single array and that is what is looped over.

Comment: Have you tried to print the array after the the query?
Try print_r($result) to check what values does the Database gives you.